# Shared builder containers in Docker or Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My project is structured kind of like this:

```
project
|- docker_compose.yml
|- svc-a
   |- Dockerfile
|- svc-b
   |- Dockerfile
|- common-lib
   |- Dockerfile
```

Within `docker_compose.yaml`:

```
version: 3.7
services:
  common-lib:
    build:
      context: ./common-lib/
    image: common-lib:latest
  svc-a:
    depends_on:
      - common-lib
    build:
       ...
  svc-b:
    depends_on:
      - common-lib
    build:
      ...
```

In `common-lib/Dockerfile` relatively standard:

```
FROM someBuilderBase:latest
COPY . .
RUN build_libraries.sh
```

Then in `svc-a/Dockerfile` I import those built libraries:

```
FROM common-lib:latest as common-lib

FROM someBase:latest
COPY --from=common-lib ./built ./built-common-lib
COPY . .
RUN build_service_using_built_libs.sh
```

And the Dockerfile for svc-b is basically the same.

This works great using `docker-compose build svc-a` as it first builds the `common-lib` container because of that `depends-on` and I can reference to it easily with `common-lib:latest`. It is also great because running `docker-compose build svc-b` doesn't rebuild that base common library.

My problem is that I am defining a *builder container* as a docker compose service. When I run `docker-compose up` it attempts to run the `common-lib` as a running binary/service and spits out a slew of errors. In my real project I have a bunch of chains of these *builder container services* which is making `docker-compose up` unusuable.

I am relatively new to docker, is there a more canonical way to do this while a) avoiding code duplication building common-lib in multiple Dockerfiles and b) avoiding a manual re-run of `docker build ./common-lib` before running `docker build ./svc-a (or b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do it is *not exactly* how you should do it in Docker.

You have two options to achieve what you want :

### 1/ Multi stage build

This is almost what you're doing with this line (in your `svc-a` dockerfile)

```
FROM common-lib:latest as common-lib
```

However, instead of creating you `common-lib` image in another project, just copy the dockerfile content in your service :

```
FROM someBuilderBase:latest as common-lib
COPY . .
RUN build_libraries.sh

FROM someBase:latest
COPY --from=common-lib ./built ./built-common-lib
COPY . .
RUN build_service_using_built_libs.sh
```

This way, you won't need to add a `common-lib` service in docker-compose.

### 2/ Inheritance

If you have a lot of images that need to use what is inside your `common-lib` (and you don't want to add it in **every** dockerfile with multi stage build), then you can just use inheritance.

**What's inheritance in docker ?**

It's a **base image**.
From your example, `svc-a` image is based on `someBase:latest`. I guess, it's the same for `svc-b`. In that case, just add the lib you need in `someBase` image (with multi-stage build for example or by creating a base image containing your lib).

Comment: With the complexity of my actual project I feel like 1) is out of the question because it will mean a ton of code duplication. With 2) it kind of goes against what I am trying to avoid which is needing to run `docker build ./common-lib` anytime I tweak something in common lib that also shows up in `svc-a` or `svc-b`. Tweaking something in `common-lib` and getting it to show up in a running `svc-a` will require at least 2 build operations. I like inheritance but I want it to auto-rebuild the base if something has changed. Docker compose does this except it has that annoying `up` issue.

Comment: I understand that solution 1 is a pain if you have *a lot* of images that need those libs. About solution 2, this is actually the *best practice* by docker, see [this article](https://success.docker.com/article/mta-best-practices#imagehierarchy). What you're doing rigth now is good, but you have two constraints : you'll need to have the `common-lib` service in your docker-compose and you won't be able to share your compose without the source code.